# How to DUMP API request information to a TXT file in PHP?

Tags: php, api

I am working on API for DHRU CMS.

Unfortunately there are NO API setting to modify API CALLs, I can only provide domain: www.mydomain.com and Press SYNC. Then it will make a call to www.mydomain.com/api/index.php

Content of /api/**index.php** below:

```
   <?php
    if(!extension_loaded('ionCube Loader')){$__oc=strtolower(substr(php_uname(),0,3));
    $__ln='ioncube_loader_'.$__oc.'_'.substr(phpversion(),0,3).(($__oc=='win')?'.dll':'.so');
    if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();
    }
    $__ln='/ioncube/'.$__ln;
    $__oid=$__id=realpath(ini_get('extension_dir'));
    $__here=dirname(__FILE__);if(strlen($__id)>1&&$__id[1]==':'){$__id=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__id,2));
    $__here=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__here,2));
    }$__rd=str_repeat('/..',substr_count($__id,'/')).$__here.'/';
    $__i=strlen($__rd);
    while($__i--){if($__rd[$__i]=='/'){$__lp=substr($__rd,0,$__i).$__ln;if(file_exists($__oid.$__lp)){$__ln=$__lp;
    break;
    }}}if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);
    }}else{die('The file '.__FILE__." is corrupted.\n");
    }if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();
    }echo('Site error: the file <b>'.__FILE__.'</b> requires the ionCube PHP Loader '.basename($__ln).' to be installed by the website operator. If you are the website operator please use the <a href="http://www.ioncube.com/lw/">ionCube Loader Wizard</a> to assist with installation.');
    exit(199);
    ?>
    HR+cP/ElGN2OERf73MJKKmN0O3NzOb4pGJD4uAtGY1PaUwYj7l+JHDMBep4pqmahy4Kl4sfAGrTZ
    aL2G93Ks855rHFW7zCB0T54xRH9H3qrSrF0bW8cu82ephdXnKG7gU+xqeIGYrhCDtjkrnbjxfTW6
    SPgO1ywEMkU6IXNYZ/qD4SE3xzccXKU68rw9qYO6SWnfNL48ek9+x1+AhB1etCJY5QRNVub/Y7XI
    n42bVdO8Xx4gEGoUd5OI3lCEqfl2ojsJVJ5rHz8glJ798zsRYapbyXrQw6JU2u7f7mh1CjbJ5RBa
    jWL/SqHd/M7MYfblBiTdEi45H444RK66kWf3/ubHaIum4m5VMsXpG5CRiVSOWfDL2POK0S9gsFyk
    aUQBqJIkBirzm+/jdQaVFun5FJMf5lSB8Lb0KX0KmfLBiwYy9kLsGSNB7XCLOyJdFKNE7GjpPR3f
    DIXXUSCiq4NjJ1DBc58FhrMIcRadT6muczYvxmenoA8AtIY/zF5YBsjzzFCivOlpWzHwfGheRTOv
    PFTGwDQJCq5BsULjUKRmd0BN0hgY8/wGurwtYDtIS1gM5lfiZYeWl8gdDE7UWvZywSIpEilnFfiW
    f13lcxq4pHC0l8ff7b9duqETtzfRjqDiHAXJi+liNKVJjXVLo5EybeYEJHh3N+ivjP3zWtWMX3NI
    Cm8Xx5N6qak4jFNtzo2BmH1yyDU3LAjrI2uDmckCtE6ZYwxsZlOXAlrwtiwEyPOZOZQ4c8mOhQv4
    WiZCjkNfholywBh3DehwJLc5vM7hAEwVPAJuyduj+cOR059eQyfxuk9DtHyFsMTu4diXYuhZa2cm
    nleD/HBoImYkEy+W3h8Y9SUXUDV3w/1ZPSX29ZPpYClis4Sc+V0t2b/kS/+GeVf4tvyZ6LzKn1Ej
    +61dQ4NMAbGu0rYNJs0t3xruPNOdJ9IJHshPAOpJi2cQPbII8KAqbR1+B0cDWkUSmfYsXAqMJqc7
    NioSFduxtUkDXL1Lhl4VFIb1JHC7/uMD5aOhKYIq53if8zPvI7SX7bU9RglGA0M64vondAbXwh1A
    2xdT+vtQFYa10kA3FaqPtByxmUho0chuA2utqnXCU6qtqZa1Wvdl3mx6kSXEe+I3ENYevLucve+m
    GXLQ6l2uDVdnjqiLtPjRK5Ss/zktgTU2vHSFCSAzl7oW5tCDjazNr45ebpqXMWIZ/N6iyDytG8lN
    CbG60jkeTRb5mVdg/r7jqPVYUpeGvnsfcIK4vfo1rAjQzE16vf1f5FkRe/FJ7aLbCrf2HfE3PVrE
    dexHXHVpec1GtBkAcZPEpPrPGldbz84oEpAeLkXBpXCpnB9vPZZR3fXJKwSO4PpqD8FxO2cm8gkL
    gmGK83ii++SqADkcNv667gOk0cB/+7uv5IVKVYrMcLqOQKxybTDaHYNR1TYnua3mJESMFwvy+yRO
    DK2PaBNLGI3S+1u5R0Vvyyvfm/HJZw1w71O7v37N0ubVaJrbTv5QyJ5KFGxSDG/EYIaI/NbdjP9f
    XKszlcHjU8NcVpvrGzUQAfmkzLW21/04+mZpfuolV/CsA2rP0KKFuE+IqxAPTan/6H9PfVnY9OZ/
    kHi47EptJlJQr2ZLeqDOY5HJFPN6ynuPksgQnn9Pzo/7HUGkqJHISRTa4HUEWBSB3UKI+6SC0w6q
    DfTvPpj8Zfh/DuX+J7k9WWTh88U91MXQv4PO3iuhYymKjjAfAEdsJHKCsp81CNsSHV/VSXJB00Yw
    0059QtJNTFT5X3OTztfgSgMhDn0vEBmB0pKBOWLJKaqsOVYzyOu6TZh80WZ09K8/I2PA0+tLFMyu
    FUTXsVSEEEeFFViDC79O6ATJ2CqIUdZzgi/dfPYS3z+Epau6/Fou5gDDFGpY/c6MvOp+gwzlSAmS
    rPumQb44TmnuZAWSwmh6qYIK7v4e1Se1b9c2THmXNCF7KRqOFIVvrPyw48ZdadoVM2PG1d4DuEGM
    5EeUs5AxLX5sPM+99M90K5ACrBp8lN5aHmI/pmWvqKOXG2ebJIj/Q5W8OjzP5SFaahiGQrd1/OyG
    81gEXbC2Skf+wRdhgpInsEmDZ8Wb7+Yzyv5f4e+eG/BZ+s+eOJqtIGrpBNbtqL/2CXeBu1+5Lbe5
    5deIDBQQb7N1BhGa1DosrANj3iwlqsQ9IpEn4ntxkPjlVAyXV5wCkGTFQMgrHwCRh6KTnLhKToHs
    GSYgjkxJjSyTeJ60B3a7E/KfXPsJpw40qOkCOh3vXLrRO0dci+V0ifVAA4eA4tPJ3ylxqMHEpJID
    NG1vLkP8TVfyDvnNQZYL2t99qehZK+1RyYZ/AmkV6MBvgNJaLHFBapcEkOGgUfmO4hqFQ+uYpK/5
    2aIa2yHS2tjeQr/8qBtdd+2yekYDqG/qCU+4WeIoWfMJCHTfpVCs+m+bYku+RHeeHSsRn/A7JL0M
    G63/pTwB69kCq5N/br8Iygg2mh/uFydT/ua05lNtCxFrVVg/Hs5yBYORS1Zz7FBo7GQZI3afP6Iv
    Ul9oOTeX5rdJaYj+yp5VMKgRy2V8aISMtiEx4ne4izUyYnrNUpt5pMqXW4Dn+ZFeW4dJwK5jxpXE
    rkU1aULKBJh9KNGULnzDXQCvdu0jkKUhxvpXGkwpP1VDfdCFJUQ8jnpaWitSwrPTKqspU05+3Sp2
    Cpkem6lDm3cHmbbAru/sUo6l626fiv4qaBklZc/voZVo5X+RAVbOtFSwegeKlufkH8UsGRjRDrWI
    8WC8fh4XTuMY/3rAJ2h3tCus/9LnQE61exJUO/PkLFyhCRedRZ1DfJNS8CMJrGtFSzJVXqj3d0M/
    V9XF2nVA5onD+5HtHfjBqxJrbVqP5nu8YtKlTBZdEfau+wuvBSV0qmNV+19RGucVwAoA2cpl67/j
    3pDNnY4hmtNH/eo8Kcd7DXa8p/wWWVlF97V4niqQGCD2qe34SxH6fv0kex2X24FwlCVvnfkXkcn5
    1pyHRWX57kLudQZUXYdqxognkPhf7j7APGaPv+nupVezNI2qXyuZGLKkL449yjQnrBYKP7MlrE1s
    gS6vn5MLp0sMfpjlYterc0oF/qza1QDhPfnrQH6PgUWbA5dHOq7KUjn4q9W+H2ghedknFeEDp5Lw
    W8eLCHw4OOe5rC8JL7VT603UQdHBLxUDvFWoWfclBCBSazLCeuFy/p08gO/V7bUvrrPqI3ALYXLc
    PCZD7KQUI4qo29oJ+yrneu2hzGBFzBMWBasH9BcIK7BpZ+vWcdZ50Ev2OzwgtRC9OzxQCI30+p1j
    ldE0nq8+FKvVWqkt+dDoQNEfvQJ2bsqopkiMoeqispfuUsqYI5C7/cQbvxNlbPqDPZfikSSATzru
    Kl0jT8HmNKxuASj+yDldUhhAhLSKTucpfNbLUAGpsk277dOdT2k8ZK5UXs4cnZMTTBph5iTtdg+y
    eKukLtvt6xH2ymHsQdpaERn1ZQehrhjlnl0YGuVHJqq840A+bKqUVcbyJ3PdT8QuhWpYS5H1oBT8
    UcB3I15HN3KcKAATZJX6u9nV4iAlxKN3iZxqMfCAVpv9gAi99fXIEcvhkeoEi4ux4nYCDKVvJXnV
    8tznbh8FbfIGw7WVAcT49uzkgurX/UVACSYSMdn6wpTRTE==
```

I cant figure out what this contents means, but but the contents above is answer to API call. Now I am trying to figure out what it is asking for and how to reply.
Here I have made a simple script to read values and dump them to TXT file.
But file is empty.. No result so far with this code:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$text = var_dump($__oc);
fwrite($myfile, $text);
$text = var_dump($__ln);
fwrite($myfile, $text);
$text = var_dump($__oid);
fwrite($myfile, $text);
$text = var_dump($__id);
fwrite($myfile, $text);
$text = var_dump($__here);
fwrite($myfile, $text);
$text = var_dump($__id);
fwrite($myfile, $text);
$text = var_dump($__rd);
fwrite($myfile, $text);
$text = var_dump($__i);
fwrite($myfile, $text);
$text = var_dump($__lp);
fwrite($myfile, $text);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

I have also tried $_POST, $_GET and $_REQUEST but no result.

Is there any other way I can dump result from a API call?

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: I think `fwrite` may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @wogsland ? Excuse me, what do you mean? I tired with 'fwrite' but no output.. is there any other way to do this? A Sample or link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of fetching both $_GET and $_POST and write it to some logfile:

```
<?php
$rawpost = print_r($_POST, true);
$rawget = print_r($_GET, true);

$logfile = "/full/path/to/log/file/logfilename.log";
$fh = fopen($logfile,'a') or die("can't open the file");
fwrite($fh, "DATE: ".date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')."\r\n");
fwrite($fh, "\r\nRAW POST: =\t ".$rawpost."\r\n");
fwrite($fh, "\r\nRAW GET: =\t ".$rawget."\r\n");
fwrite($fh, "-------------------------------------------------------\r\n");
fclose($fh);
?>
```

With the above if someone posts data with the GET and POST method it will write it to the logfile. Your log file will need the proper write permissions if you are on a Linux system.

btw: The content of that index.php file is encoded with ionCube.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I got the results I was asking for :-)